# Overloading operator << in linked list

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm currently in the middle of my studies on university and I'm struggling to finish my current project. The assignment was to creat a linked list that will store number bigger than integer and add functions that will do some simple operations like <<,>>,+,-. While I have the whole linked list worked out I'm struggling to think how to overload operator << and >>. I tried few thing, googled it out but no solution actually solves my problem. General idea was to take a number as string then divide it into many 1digit numbers and put it into my list but without working << I can't even start.
My list.h

```
#ifndef LISTA_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTA_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct List {
    private:
        struct Node {
            int data;
            Node *next;
            Node(int _data, Node *_next = NULL) {
                data = _data;
                next = _next;
            }
        };
        Node *head, *tail;
        int counter;
        public:
        List();
        ~List();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& wyjscie,const List& L);
        //friend ostream& operator>>(ostream& wejscie,const List& L);
        //customowe funkcje
};

#endif // LISTA_H_INCLUDED
```

and list.cpp

```
#include "lista.h"

List::List()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    counter = 0;
}

List::~List()
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        Node *killer = head;
        head = head -> next;
        delete killer;
    }
    tail = NULL;
    counter = 0;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& wyjscie,const List& L)
{
    Node *temp;
    for(temp = L.head; temp != 0; temp = temp -> next)
    {
        wyjscie << temp -> data;
        wyjscie<<endl;
    }
    return wyjscie;
}
```

Problem is that Node is not declared in this scope and when I try to do it without this temporary Node I'm also failing since list is const.
Thanks in advance for any tips.

## EDIT

First problem solved. I moved to overloading operator>>. I created and insert(string a) function which takes the string, divides it and inserts into the linked list. After doing that I thought that overloading operator>> will be just using that function. I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
void List::insert(string a)
{
    int n=a.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
    Node *nowy=new Node(a[i]);
    if(head==nullptr)
    {
        head=nowy;
        tail=nowy;
    }
    else
    {
        (*tail).next=nowy;
        tail=nowy;
    }
    }
}
istream& operator>>(istream& wejscie,const List& L)
{
    wejscie >> List::insert(string a);
    return wejscie;
}
```

I also tried something like this:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& wejscie,const List& L)
{
    string a;
    cin >>a;
    wejscie >> L.insert(a);
    return wejscie;
}
```

My main function

```
#include "lista.h"
int main()
{
    List T1;
    List T2;
    T1.insert("54321");
    cout << T1 << endl;
    cin >> T2;
    cout << T2;

}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your current implementation of `<<`? Looks correct. Please post an [mcve] if you want us to help you.

Comment: What is your problem? (compilation error, wrong output, Segmentation Fault, etc.) Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code seem violating [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), so `List` may cause some trouble when it is copied.

Comment: Sorry, problem is that when I wanted to do the operator<< like this it says that Node from temp wasn't declared. I tried to do it without ,just on L.head but it's const so I can't change it, so I can't go through whole list.

Comment: Use `List::Node *` to identify the type of `temp`, rather than `Node *`.   Declarations in the body of`operator<<()` aren't implicitly referenced to `List`.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& wyjscie,const List& L)
```

is not linked to the `List` class, so `List` should be specified to use `Node` in that.

In other words, you should use `List::Node *temp;` instead of `Node *temp;`.

## For EDIT part

Why your programs won't work:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& wejscie,const List& L)
{
    // List::insert isn't telling which list to insert
    // "string a" here is invalid syntax
    wejscie >> List::insert(string a);
    return wejscie;
}
```

```
// L is const, so insertion won't be accepted
istream& operator>>(istream& wejscie,const List& L)
{
    string a;
    // cin suddenly appeared from somewhere
    cin >>a;
    // return type of L.insert(a) is void, so it won't suit for operand of >> operator
    wejscie >> L.insert(a);
    return wejscie;
}
```

(my guess of) What you should do is:

1. read a string from `wejscie`
2. "insert" it to `L`

An implementation of that:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& wejscie,List& L)
{
    string a;
    wejscie >> a;
    L.insert(a);
    return wejscie;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what was bothering me this whole time. I can't believe I didn't notice it earlier.

Comment: If you don't mind I would be greatful for checking my Edit part in this question.